# Simplest molecules with multiple local minima

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, optimization, vectors, polyhedra

[Methane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane) (C + 4 H) goes to a tetrahedral structure.
[Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water) (O + 2 H + 2 e-) goes to a slightly skewed tetrahedron.

In a computer model, both of these have no [local minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) problems.  There is a single [strong attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor) for both molecules.

What are the simplest molecule models that have multiple local minima?

Comment: Define simplest. In the organic world, $C_4H_{10}$ has 2 isomers, which definitely suggests 2 minima.

Comment: Simplest -- fewest atoms.

Comment: Please clarify what function you are minimizing. Just pretend (ha) that I don't know any chemistry. Thanks.